# Retrieve array name

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have written a function in c++ which receives a struct as a input. The struct object received has two arrays. I need to use both the arrays for different purposes. The array names have been created in a certain format. How to retrieve array names in a string.

```
struct INFO
{

 float fADataLHS[3] = {1,2,3};
 float fADataRHS[3] = {4,5,6};
```

Struct INFO has been defined where two arrays have been defined an initialized. The function useStruct uses both the function for different purposes.

```
void useStruct(struct *INFO)
{
  --------;
  --------;
}

int main()
{
   struct INFO info;
   useStruct(info);

}
```

I want a method in which I can retrieve the name of the array as for ex. fAdataLHS and store it to a string. The idea is to find the sub-string LHS and RHS from the string names and process then accordingly.

PS: I am quite new to c++.

Comment: If you are new to C++, don't cross tag C unless you *know* how to do it in C and want a "natural" C++ answer. In C++, you don't need to repeat the `struct`, and you *know* what the "names" of the arrays in `INFO` are, so... just use them?

Comment: If you're asking for reflection like feature (like C#) it can't be done.

Comment: in runtime i don't think you need their names. in the declaration of the struct, you showed me that the length of two arrays are determined. you can really reference them by just calculating the offset of each array.

Comment: Why do not inerith from a base abstract class that has two pure virtual methods like: "const float* getLHS()" and "const float* getRHS()"? it would be easy to implement and more C++ like.

Answer (score 2):

I will go simple as you're a begginer to C++.

If you want to use both of arrays for different purposes, just doit. For instance:

```
void use_array_for_different_purposes(INFO *info)
{
    // Purpose one, printing values using fADataLHS.
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {cout << info->fADataLHS[i] << endl;}
    // Purpose two, computing total sum using fADataRHS.
    int acum;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {acum += info->fADataRHS[i];}
}
```

As you can see, you don't need to get the arrays names as strings values.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand corectly, your use case is this: you have two (or more) names and each has a float array associated with it. You want to get the array by name and process the data.

Consider this code:

```
class INFO
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<float>> vectors;

public:

    INFO() : vectors{}
    {
        vectors["fADataLHS"] = { 1, 2, 3 };
        vectors["fADataRHS"] = { 4, 5, 6 };
    }

    const std::vector<float>& operator[](const std::string& key) const // access vector by key
    {
         return vectors.at(key);
    }

};

void useStruct(const INFO& info) // pass instance by const reference
{
    std::cout << info["fADataLHS"][0] << "\n"; // access element 0 from the fADataLHS array

    // get the entire array:
    const auto& arr = info["fADataRHS"];

    // this will throw a std::out_of_bounds
    const auto& arr = info["non-existent-key"];

}
```

**EDIT**: A few other notes:

- in C++ try not to use `float` - use `double` instead
- if you need to alter the vector contents from client code, add a non-const version of the `operator[]`